# Ionic Button Click not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

My code is pretty simple. Here is an Ionic Screen called Settings which has a thing called Hours Per Week.

```
<ion-view title="Settings">
<ion-content class="has-header">
    <ul class="list">
        <label class="item item-input item-label">
        <span class="input-label">Hours per week</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="hoursPerWeek" value="37">
        </label>
    </ul>
    <button class="button button-balanced" ng-click="submitClicked()">
       Save
    </button>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

This settings screen is using SettingsCtrl, as defined in my app.js file. Here is my controller (Edited):

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])           

.controller('SettingsCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.hoursPerWeek = '37';
    $scope.submitClicked = function(){
        localStorageService.set('hoursPerWeek',$scope.hoursPerWeek);
        console.log("Set Value of hoursPerWeek as : " + $scope.hoursPerWeek);
    }
})
```

As it is evident from above, it uses angular-local-storage module, and I have made sure it is injected into the app as in this declaration :

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'LocalStorageModule'])
```

<strike>The problem is `submitClicked()` does not seem to work. Like if I change the hours per week value to 42 (from 37) , it will seem to work for the current localhost session. When I stop the server and run it again, the value goes back to 37. I dont know whats going wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.</strike> I'm facing a new error as described in EDIT 2 below.

**EDIT 1** (FIXED):
@icewind, here is the error I am facing

```
TypeError: localStorage.get is not a function
at new <anonymous> (controllers.js:45)
at Object.instantiate (ionic.bundle.js:18015)
at $controller (ionic.bundle.js:23417)
at Object.self.appendViewElement (ionic.bundle.js:59908)
at Object.render (ionic.bundle.js:57901)
at Object.init (ionic.bundle.js:57821)
at Object.self.render (ionic.bundle.js:59767)
at Object.self.register (ionic.bundle.js:59725)
at updateView (ionic.bundle.js:65400)
at ionic.bundle.js:65377
```

**EDIT 2:**

This time I have no errors. I am able to call the submitClicked() from the Save button but the problem now is, the value gets reset back to 37. I've added a console log function in the submitClicked() function as in the edited controller code above.

I'm trying to modify the value of hoursPerWeek by typing in 42, and when I click the Save button, the thing I'm getting on the console is :

```
Set Value of hoursPerWeek as : 37
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use value from localStorage if available

```
.controller('SettingsCtrl', function($scope, localStorageService) {
    $scope.hoursPerWeek = localStorageService.get('hoursPerWeek') || 37;
    $scope.submitClicked = function(){
        localStorageService.set('hoursPerWeek',$scope.hoursPerWeek);
    }
})
```

And configure your injector to provide it. Otherwise you're just saved it and never used

Comment: Hello sir, I tried running your code, but it seems like Ionic Lab on my system isnt liking this. When I use your code, my Settings view does not load at all. It instead redirects to the default `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise()` view I've defined. But when I set the value of hoursPerWeek to 37, the code seems to work for the current session but doesn't after a Stop and Start

Comment: I don't know how to check that in ionic lab. I could open the ionic project on chrome.could you please tell how do I check console?

Comment: If you opened it in chrome launch developer tools. `ctrl/cmd + alt +I`

Comment: Here's the error
`TypeError: localStorage.get is not a function
    at new <anonymous> (controllers.js:45)
    at Object.instantiate (ionic.bundle.js:18015)
    at $controller (ionic.bundle.js:23417)
    at Object.self.appendViewElement (ionic.bundle.js:59908)
    at Object.render (ionic.bundle.js:57901)
    at Object.init (ionic.bundle.js:57821)
    at Object.self.render (ionic.bundle.js:59767)
    at Object.self.register (ionic.bundle.js:59725)
    at updateView (ionic.bundle.js:65400)
    at ionic.bundle.js:65377`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fixed my code. I've made little changes to my HTML. It looks almost similar to the time I asked the question :

```
<ion-view title="Settings">
<ion-content class="has-header">
    <ul class="list">
        <label class="item item-input item-label">
        <span class="input-label">Hours per week</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="config.hoursPerWeek">
        </label>
    </ul>
    <button class="button button-balanced" ng-click="save()">
           Save
    </button>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Here comes the controller. I've had to make a few changes here. It now looks like this :

```
.controller('SettingsCtrl' , function($scope, localStorageService) {
    $scope.config = {
        hoursPerWeek: localStorage.getItem('hoursPerWeek' , 37) || 37
    };

    $scope.save = function() {
     console.log($scope.config.hoursPerWeek);
     localStorage.setItem('hoursPerWeek', $scope.config.hoursPerWeek);
    };
})
```

@icewind 's idea actually motivated this answer.

Thanks.